# Bed24 custom payment integration

Tags: php

I am trying to integrate a custom payment gateway (paystack) on [beds24](https://beds24.com/) using PHP. Can someone help put me through pls

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I already created the booking page
add the paystack redirect ur l to the url page on bed24
also the post data has been added: deposit=[PAYMENTAMOUNT]&bookid={BOOKID]